# ORA-01219: database or pluggable database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables or views only

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle19c, pluggable-database

I'm using oracle 19c. When i tried to open pluggable database as:

```
alter pluggable database pdbname open;
```

I got this error:

> ORA-01219: database or pluggable database not open: queries allowed on
> fixed tables or views only

Comment: The alert log might give more useful information.